# Reusing Database Connections With Azure Functions Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, azure-functions

I cannot find clear information on how to manage database connections (MongoDB in my case) from an Azure function written in Javascript.

The Microsoft document below says to not create a connection for each invocation of the function by using static variables in C# using .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server and the pooling is handled by the client connection.  It does not describe how to do this in Javascript.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

A solution of creating a global variable to hold the database client between invocations is described here but the author is not confident this is the correct way to do it.

http://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-azure-functions-and-mongodb.html

Has anyone used this in production or understand if this is the correct approach?

Comment: Refer to MongoClient Connection Pooling section here and use similar pattern in your Azure Function. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's a very close equivalence between C#/SQL storing a single SqlConnection instance in a static variable and JS/MongoDB storing a single Db instance in a global variable. The basic pattern for JS/MongoDB in Azure Functions is (assuming you're up to date for async/await - alternatively you can use callbacks as per your linked article):

```
// getDb.js

let dbInstance;

module.exports = async function() {
    if (!dbInstance) {
        dbInstance = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    }
    return dbInstance;
};

// function.js

const getDb = require('./getDb.js');

module.exports = async function(context, trigger) {
    let db = await getDb();
    // ... do stuff with db ..
};
```

This will mean you only instantiate one Db object per host instance. Note this isn't one per Function App - if you're using a dedicated App Service Plan then there will be the number of instances you've specified in the plan, and if you're using a Consumption Plan then it'll vary depending on how busy your app is.

Comment: This answer is a life-saver. I didn't know that global variables are passed around the entire host instance and I thought the connection dies along with any variables after an execution is done. Since it's supposed to be a stateless function

Comment: My question for you @MarkXA is - what would be the maximum concurrent functions utilizing this single connection simultaneously before something breaks?

Comment: The client itself shouldn't actually break - it'll just wait if the connection pool is full. More generally it'll depend on your actual database. If it's fixed scale then yes it can become a bottleneck if Azure Functions gets too busy. If it's set to autoscale (e.g. Cosmos DB using the MongoDB API) then that should be less of a problem.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for that clarification. Much appreciated

Comment: Isn't this code containing a race condition? What would a safer code looks like?

Comment: npm install your-favourite-async-lock-package :)